# Facebook authentication won't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My website is using Facebook Connect, but since a month it's not working. I suspect that Facebook changed something. I tried to find out, but it was impossible. I have a Java file that initiates the authentication, but I don't know if that file is the problem. Well, basically it connect, but it's not returning the registration form of my website.

```js
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({appId: cfg_facebook_app_id, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true}); 


    //initial login check
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        //logged in, force logout
        FB.logout(function() {
          //logged out, subscribe to events
          loginEvents();
        });
    } else {
        //not logged in
        loginEvents();
    }
});

function loginEvents() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        // do something with response
        logout();
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        login(response);
        //login redirects the user. Before logout fires()
        });
        }

     };
    (function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.type = 'text/javascript';
e.src = document.location.protocol +
    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

    function login(){
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    window.location = cfg_site_url + 'facebook_auth.php?hashcode='+response.id;
});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try{} updating to the new version of javascript sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

> As of December 13th, 2011, the JavaScript SDK now only supports OAuth
>   2.0 for authentication. The ability to enable OAuth 2.0 in the JS SDK was first introduced in July. All apps were given until October 1,
>   2011 to test and migrate. With this change, please ensure that you are
>   using FB.getAuthResponse to obtain the access token.